# Limit rows with certain values in database

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jpa, transactions

I have an application written in java that is running on multiple jvms and writing to the same database.
I have an entity called: `request` that has these columns: id, userId, text

I want to limit the amount of requests that an user can post to 3

I cannot write a code like:

```
line1  open transaction
line2  check if requests for that userId are less than 3
line3  if yes insert that record
line4  else abort
line5  close transaction
```

because since the jvms are 2, it's possible that one thread of jvm1 is executing `line2` while another thread of jvm2 is executing the same line.
So both threads in their respective transaction (tx1 and tx2, in jvm1 and jvm2) thinks that there are less than 3 records and will commit the transaction.

One solution could be write a flag in a different table and use that flag to locking that part of code, but I would prefer another solution.

Have you some idea?

**Update**:

Im using JPA, so Im searching a way where I still can use it to achieve this result.

Comment: Add an extra INT column `req_num` not-null with a CHECK constraint that allows values between 1 and 3 only. Then add a UNIQUE constraint with the column (userId, req_num).

Comment: Another solution is to use a secondary table to store the "sequence numbers per userId". Then use optimistic locking to avoid database locks.

Comment: @TheImpaler The first solution is nice, please post as answer instead of comment so I can mark this as accepted answer if noone will post something better :)  
Regarding the second solution I just have a table like this but as you write "sequence numbers per userId" are **per userId** but in this case I have **per userId and request** so I cannot use a generic table for every entity that has this problem and creating a table specific for every entity seems a bit overkill to me ^^

Comment: Why do you want do this?  What are the consequences of failure?  If someone spends a week orchestrating a race condition to let themselves checkout one extra library book, do I really need to care? (Just make sure to bring it back, son)  Do you have a table of unique userid's which could serve as a locking target?  Do you need to be able to find the problem through a query you manually check (with success) before committing, or would it be okay if the offender just gets thrown an error upon commit?

Answer (score 2):

You'll also have a `users` table, the PK of which is referenced by `userId`.

One solution is to take a lock on the corresponding row in the `users` table before updating rows in the `request` table. Concurrent transactions trying to operate on requests for the same user have to wait to obtain the same lock until the previous transaction has committed / rolled back. Like:

```
BEGIN;

SELECT FROM users
WHERE id = 123
FOR NO KEY UPDATE;  -- strong enough

INSERT INTO requests (...)
SELECT ... -- your constants here
FROM   request 
WHERE  userid = 123
HAVING count(*) < 3;  -- ①

DELETE ...

UPDATE ...

COMMIT;
```

① While the `SELECT` list only has constants, the query works without `GROUP BY`. `HAVING count(*) < 3` skips the `INSERT` if at least 3 rows are found - without raising an exception.

[`FOR NO KEY UPDATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE) is weaker than `FOR UPDATE` in that it still allows concurrent writes as long as key columns are not changed. Good enough for your task.

You just need to make certain that all relevant write access to `request` takes this approach.

Comment: I really like your solution, very clean. Btw I'm using JPA as ORM and with this approach I have to copy/paste this SQL in every repository for every entity that has this "problem", since every entity has different constants to put in the SELECT.  
If I wanted to "generalize" it I'll lose type safety because I'll have a list of `Expressions` as input but if I add or remove a colum (i.e. field) in my entity this query will fail only at runtime.  
My fault that I didn't specify that im using JPA in the question, I've just updated it.